# Intel 80x86 PE Code Translation

Tags: x86, portable-executable

I'm currently trying to understand the translation of the following PE Code instruction:

```
004033C0 | .-E9 3BDCFFFF | JMP seh_exam.00401000
```

I did a little  bit of research on my own and since it is an unconditional jump I assume it is the instruction found on the following table:

[image]

**(Image source: http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#jmp )**

From my understanding, the byte E9 = unconditional jump and, 3B = o0 and DC = 01, where o0 and 01 represent the offset to set the EIP to.

The code jumps up by 9152  bytes, but how exactly does the translation of negative offsets work? Any advice would be appreciated.

PS: not a homework question.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of plain text. You're better than that, we know that because you're willing to tackle a difficult programming field.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry, removed the first screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instruction in your question is a `JMP rel32`, which isn't included in the table you've shown. You should probably be using a better reference, such as [Intel's Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals).

The bytes `3B DC FF FF` in a [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) layout (which is what x86 processors use) form the 32-bit doubleword `FFFFDC3B`. In [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) the value `FFFFDC3B` equals `-23C5`.

Your jump instruction begins at `4033C0` and is 5 bytes long. Since the jump displacement is relative to the beginning of the next instruction you get the jump target `4033C0 + 5 - 23C5 == 401000`. Alternatively you could write that as `truncate_to_32_bits(4033C0 + 5 + FFFFDC3B)`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up. Answered any further questions that could have arisen.